# Assign fields from database to text boxes when selected respective ID in LARAVEL 5

Tags: laravel-5.1

I am new to Laravel framework. I am working in Laravel 5.1. My question is very simple:

I have One  Dynamic Select box in the form, which contains ID 1,2,3,...

Followed with few textboxes like Name, Addres, Contact etc.

I want to auto fill the text boxes from database when I select respective ID.

I would be very thankful, if one can share code I have to write in view & Controller.

Please suggest any relative tutorial if possible.

Thanks

**View:**

```html
 <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{!! csrf_token() !!}" id="_token" >

 <label for="reqid" class="col-lg-2 control-label">* Permission Requester</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10" >
        <select class="form-control" name="permission-requester"  id="permission-requester" onchange= "getvisitorinfo(this.value)"  >
            <option disabled selected></option>
            @foreach($permissionrequesters as $permissionrequester)
                <option value="{{$permissionrequester->id}}" @if (old('permission-requester')==$permissionrequester->name) selected="selected" @endif>{{$permissionrequester->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>

 <div class="col-xs-push-12">
                <table class="table" border="1" >
                    <thead>
                    <tr><td colspan="6" style="background-color: #009d8d  "> <font style="color: #ffffff">Permission Requester Details</font></td> </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{Input::old('requester-name')}}" id="reqname" name="reqname"> </td>
                        <th>Relation</th>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{Input::old('requester-relation')}}" id="reqrelation" name="reqrelation"> </td>
                        <th>Contact No.</th>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{Input::old('requester-contact')}}" id="requester-contact" name="requester-contact"> </td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <th>Occupation</th>
                        <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{Input::old('requester-occupation')}}" id="requester-occupation" name="requester-occupation"> </td>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <td colspan="3"><input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{Input::old('requester-address')}}" id="requester-address" name="requester-address"> </td>
                    </tr>
                
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

**JS:**

```js
<script>
  

   function getvisitorinfo(visitor_id){

    var formData    =   {
        'visitor_id':visitor_id,
        '_token':_token
    };

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: '/visitorinfo',
        data:formData,
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(data){
            var res_status       =   data.status;
            var res_message      =   data.message;
            var res_data         =   data.data; //your DB data

            if(res_status == 'success'){
                $('#reqname').val(res_data.relation);
                $('#reqrelation').val(res_data.relation);



            }else if(res_status == 'fail'){
                alert('error')
            }
        },
        error:function(){
            alert('error')
        }
    });
}
 

 </script>
```

**Controller: studpermitController.php**

```js
public function visitorinfo(Request $request)
    {   

        $visitor_id   =   $request->input('visitor_id');           

            $visitorinfo   = authorise_d::where('id',$visitor_id)->first()->toArray();

        if(sizeof($visitorinfo) > 0){            
            $data   =   ['status'=>'success','message'=>'Visitor Allowed','data'=>$visitorinfo];
        }else{
            $data   =   ['status'=>'fail','message'=>'Not Valid Visitor','data'=>''];
        }

        return  Response::json($data);

    }
```

**Route**

```js
Route::post('/visitorinfo','studpermitController@visitorinfo');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the way to solution. Many Thanks to "Qazi" for the great help.
Just putting my final code  (reduced to my requirment) which is working perfectly for me, and may helpful for others like me:

**Route:**

```js
Route::post('/visitorinfo','studpermitController@visitorinfo');
```

**View (taken partial/relate code)**

```html
 <meta name="_token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}"/> 
<label for="reqid" class="col-lg-2 control-label">* Permission Requester</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10" >
        <select class="form-control" name="permission-requester"  id="permission-requester" onchange= "getvisitorinfo(this.value)"  >
            <option disabled selected></option>
            @foreach($permissionrequesters as $permissionrequester)
                <option value="{{$permissionrequester->id}}" @if (old('permission-requester')==$permissionrequester->name) selected="selected" @endif>{{$permissionrequester->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>

<div class="col-xs-push-12">
                <table class="table" border="1" >
                    <thead>
                    <tr><td colspan="6" style="background-color: #009d8d  "> <font style="color: #ffffff">Permission Requester Details</font></td> </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{Input::old('requester-name')}}" id="reqname" name="reqname"> </td>
                        <th>Relation</th>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{Input::old('requester-relation')}}" id="reqrelation" name="reqrelation"> </td>
                        <th>Contact No.</th>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{Input::old('requester-contact')}}" id="requester-contact" name="requester-contact"> </td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <th>Occupation</th>
                        <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{Input::old('requester-occupation')}}" id="requester-occupation" name="requester-occupation"> </td>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <td colspan="3"><input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{Input::old('requester-address')}}" id="requester-address" name="requester-address"> </td>
                    </tr>
                
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

**studpermitController.php**

```js
public function visitorinfo(Request $request)
{   

     $visitor_id   =  $request->input('visitor_id');   
     $visitorinfo   = authorise_d::where('id',$visitor_id)->first()->toArray();
    
    return ($visitorinfo);
   
}
```

**JS**

```js
  

  function getvisitorinfo(visitor_id){

    var route='/visitorinfo';
    var data =   {'visitor_id':visitor_id,};

    $.ajaxSetup({
   headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
    });

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:route,
        data:data,
       
        success:function(data){
              
                $('#reqname').val(data.name);
                $('#reqrelation').val(data.relation);

        },
        error:function(){
            alert('error')
        }
    });
}
 

 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some some sample code for your understanding, I hope it will help you to solve your problem. adjust Requested Route URL and code as per your need.

**HTML/View**

```
<select name="state_id" id="state_id" onchange="getStateCourses(this.value)">
  <option value="0">All States</option>
  <option value="1">Alabama</option>
  <option value="2">Alaska</option>
  <option value="3">Arizona</option>
  <option value="4">Arkansas</option>
  <option value="5">California</option>
  <option value="6">Colorado</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
function getStateCourses(state_id){

    var formData    =   {
        'state_id':state_id,
        '_token':_token
    };

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: adminBaseURL+'/reports/statecourses',
        data:formData,
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(data){
            var res_status       =   data.status;
            var res_message      =   data.message;
            var res_data         =   data.data; //your DB data

            if(res_status == 'success'){
                $('#name').val(res_data.name);
                $('#address').val(res_data.address);



            }else if(res_status == 'fail'){
                alert('error')
            }
        },
        error:function(){
            alert('error')
        }
    });
}
```

**Controller Method**

```
   public function postStateCourses(Request $request){
        $state_id   =   $request->input('state_id');           

            $courses_list   = Courses::where('state_id',$state_id)->first()->toArray();

        if(sizeof($courses_list) > 0){            
            $data   =   ['status'=>'success','message'=>'State courses found!','data'=>$courses_list];
        }else{
            $data   =   ['status'=>'fail','message'=>'State courses not found!','data'=>''];
        }

        return  Response::json($data);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response..  I  tried with the help of solution your provided but not succeeded.  I think, I am very close.  Kindly review my code added in the question especially routing part. I think i am doing some mistake there.

Comment: Your code is almost correct, what error you are getting? tell me do you understand what is _token in JS code ?? actually its form CSRF token, so Just replace this line `'_token':_token` by this `'_token':$('input[name="_token"]').val() also use any debug tool like firebug for JS request and response. Dump your `dd($visitor_id);` in controller, check that you getting correct ID or not.

Comment: Thanks Qazi, dd($visitor_id); & firebug debugging tool  helped me alot.